# Why does the Garuda Purana say that the Mahabharata has been undergoing interpolations since Satya yuga?

Tags: mahabharata, garuda-purana, interpolation

In the Garuda Purāna, we come across the following verse-

> दैत्याः सर्व विप्रकुलेषु भूत्वा कृते युगे भारते षट्सहस्र्याम् ।
> निष्कास्य कांश्चिन्नवनिर्मितानां निवेशनं तत्र कुर्वन्ति नित्यम् ॥
> ३,१.६९ ॥
>
> In Bharatavarsa, in the golden age (satyayuga) the daityas are born in
> the brahmin families. **They take some Verses out of the Bharata
> (Mahabharata) consisting of 6000 verses and replace them by new ones.**

~ Garuda Purana Brahma Khanda Chapter 1

But the Mahabharata itself was compiled in the Dvāparayuga, so how is it possible for it to undergo interpolations since the Satya Yuga?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any term in Shloka pointing that the term “युगे” means Satyayug. See context of whole chapter, rather then picking a Shloka, it is clear that the chapter is discussing about Kaliyuga.

For context you can see Shloka 43 which is talking about the important Puranas of **Kaliyuga**.

Comment: The Shloka mentions 'Krte Yuge' or Kritayuga which is another term for Satyuga. You may consult any translation of your choice

Comment: @Exnihilio I didn’t paid attention as I was aware of such Shloka earlier but in those versions the word used was “कलौ” not Krite.

Comment: I haven't found the word 'Kalau' in this particular verse  in the Sanskrit editions of the Garuda Purana I checked. If you have any edition which mentions this please do send the link. Thanks

Comment: @Exnihilio That is not an edition but from a 2017 article I read a few Puranas but skipped this one because, in my local culture, it is only read when someone dies. Link: http://aryamantavya.in/kya-manu-smriti-men-prakshep-hein/

Comment: So it's not from any known edition. As for articles, I'd always take them with a grain of salt unless I verify what they state. As far as I have seen, no edition of the GP really mentions 'Kalau' in the place of 'Krte'